# See data passed after onclick event from client to server in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

How to see the data being passed from client side to server side after the onclick event of a button is fired in classic asp.net.

I have a form in classic asp.net aspx page. When I click on submit button, the onclick event of the respective button is fired. In the network tab of chrome I can see an encrypted data being passed from client to server. Is there any way to see what data is passed from the client to server ?

Comment: Why don't you post your ASPX page and let us understand better your code? (and the aspx.cs page as well)

Comment: hmm.. it is not typical to reference ASP.NET Webforms as Classic ASP.NET.  We say 'Classic' for 'Classic ASP' (which is ASP.NET 1.1) to distinguish on the Web Server pipeline mode.

Comment: you are asking: "Is there any way to see what data is passed from the client to server?" but you know how to see that data (i.e. network tab of chrome).  what you really mean to ask is "how to decode/decrypt that data in the client to see it?", right?.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Dev Environment and the behavior is not custom, you can set the view and control state encryption on and off through configuration:  here is a general reference to ASP.NET State Management https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb386448%28v%3dvs.100%29#securing-view-state ... to give a proper answer - we need to know what sort of data you're talking about. Control State does include text fields, so I think it's probably that..

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into asp.net tracing. First enable tracing in your web.config. You'll want to set pageOutput="true" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/0x5wc973(v=vs.140)
 and then Set Trace="true" & TraceMode="SortByCategory" in the page directive.